# Selenium Junit to find element

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new to selenium.I am creating test script for duplicate registration into a website .When an error is displayed for duplicate registration i want to pass the testcase .
I am getting confused regarding the property of the webelement . I am not sure as to which field should i take or as how to write the findelement for the error image displayed.

Here is the HTML tag for the element image displayed:

```
<td>
    <img src="images/bell.png">
</td>
```

This is for the text displayed along with error image :

```
<a onclick="if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.forms['navigation'],'navigation:j_id322,navigation:j_id322','');}return false" style="color:#000000;" href="#">Found 1 patient(s) with same Patient Name, Gender and Age. Click here to view details</a>
```

Please help .Thanks

Comment: HTML tag is   <td>
           <img src="images/bell.png">
       </td>

Answer (score 0):

Based purely on the details provided, the following would work;

```
findElement(By.css("td>img[src='images/bell.png']")
```

and

```
findElement(By.css("a[onclick]")
```

However, I am sure that there is more context than this. Without the full html it is hard to give better solutions